# How to omit header values in Word formula?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, worksheet-function

I am new to superuser. Kindly pardon if I make some mistakes.

I am working with tables having numerical data in Word (no not even embedded Excel tables - don't ask why).
It so happens that many tables have headers/sub headers with numerical values too.
When I use formula "=SUM(ABOVE)" the expected total shouldn't pick the header value. But it does !

See the following sample. "Total (E)" represents what I expect and "Total (A)" is what I see.

```
|----------|---------------|-------|
| Header A |    Header B   | Total |
|          |---------------|       |
|          | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |       |
|----------|---------------|-------|
| One      | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 10    |
|----------|---|---|---|---|-------|
| Two      | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1     |
|----------|---|---|---|---|-------|
| Three    | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1     |
|----------|---|---|---|---|-------|
| Total (E)| 4 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 12    |
|----------|---|---|---|---|-------|

|----------|---|---|---|---|-------|
| Total (A)| 5 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 22    |
|----------|---|---|---|---|-------|
```

I know I can correct the right bottom total by changing from "=SUM(LEFT)" to "=SUM(ABOVE)"
But my real question is: How does one make Word omit the header values when picked up other totals ?
I read somewhere that we can specify ranges such as "=SUM(b3:b5)". However, my tables are many in number and vary in terms of number of rows & columns. It would be a lot of manual effort to edit all those formulae. Is there some trick such as using "=SUM(b3:bN)" (literal N) so that it picks up everything under b2 to calculate the sum ?

If version matters, I'm trying this on Word 2010. But my document (docx) will be modified using Word 2007 too.
Thanks in advance!
Parag Doke

Comment: I have posted the same question on the MS Forums. Here is the link: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/how-to-omit-header-values-from-sum-formula/a4126b10-1925-485a-9a61-5b4f09ddec48.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three quick and dirty solutions:

1. Change the numbers below Header B to words: One, Two, Three, Four.

   ```
   |----------|--------------------------|-------|
   | Header A |         Header B         | Total |
   |          |--------------------------|       |
   |          | One | Two | Three | Four |       |
   ```
2. Add a text character either before or after the numbers below Header B: either `~4` or `4~`.  Change the color of the character to white (or the color of the background) so that it can't be seen.

   ```
   |----------|-------------------|-------|
   | Header A |      Header B     | Total |
   |          |-------------------|       |
   |          | ~1 | ~2 | ~3 | ~4 |       |
   ```

   or

   ```
   |----------|-------------------|-------|
   | Header A |      Header B     | Total |
   |          |-------------------|       |
   |          | 1~ | 2~ | 3~ | 4~ |       |
   ```
3. Insert a blank row between the header numbers and the rest of the numbers.  You can then edit the borders, change the font size, etc. to make it look better.

   ```
   |----------|---------------|-------|
   | Header A |    Header B   | Total |
   |          |---------------|       |
   |          | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |       |
   |----------|---------------|-------|
   |                                  |
   |----------------------------------|
   | One      | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 10    |
   |----------|---|---|---|---|-------|
   ```